# MathJax Parenthesis - Missing or unrecognized delimiter for \right

Tags: pandoc, mathjax, docfx

I am using MathJax to attempt to render equations with .NET & DocFX.

This equation gives *Missing or unrecognized delimiter for \right* error in the browser.

```
\(D_{text{mi}} = 1 - \frac{U_{c}}{U_{i}} = C_{t} - 0.05 - \lbrack \left( 16C_{t} - 0.5 \right) I_{\text{amb}}/1000\rbrack\)
```

However if I run it in https://www.mathjax.org/#demo then it previewscorrectly.

[image]

Here is my script:

```
{!Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.}}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{_rel}}styles/docfx.vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{_rel}}styles/docfx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{_rel}}styles/main.js"></script>

<!-- configure MathJax object to define tex macros -->
<!-- Don't forget to escape \, since js also uses \ -->
<script>

MathJax = {
  tex: {
    packages: ['base'],        // extensions to use
    inlineMath: [              // start/end delimiter pairs for in-line math
      ['\\(', '\\)']
    ],
    displayMath: [             // start/end delimiter pairs for display math
      ['$$', '$$'],
      ['\[', '\]'],
      ['\(', '}\)'],
      ['\(','\)'],
      ['\\[', '\\]'],
    ],
  }
};

</script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `displayMath` settings are a bit strange.  Note that the strings `'\('` and `'\('` in javascript represent the characters `(` and `)` (no backslashes), so you have set plain old parentheses (and plain old brackets) to be display math delimiters (while your `inlineMath` parameters set `\(` and `\)` as the inline math delimiters).  I suspect that the displayMath delimiters are being found first, and so your expression

```
\(D_{text{mi}} = 1 - \frac{U_{c}}{U_{i}} = C_{t} - 0.05 - \lbrack \left( 16C_{t} - 0.5 \right) I_{\text{amb}}/1000\rbrack\)
```

is matching the

```
( 16C_{t} - 0.5 \right)
```

as displayed math (with its delimiters), making the math being processed be `16C_{t} - 0.5 \right`.  In this case, the `\right` *is* missing its argument (because you have parentheses set as display-math delimiters).

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with your `displayMath` settings, but I suspect they are the source of the problem.